# Why is the LogCat showing IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

I found a strange crash error. I made defined an Alert dialog whose context I obtained using getListView().getContext(). But the logcat shows IllegalStateException. This could be because when I close the activity before the findInBackGround() method gets excecuted, it would have no context since the activity is terminated and the method findInBackGround() executes in background and would still execute in background.
The java code snippet is

```
public class InboxFragment extends ListFragment {
protected List<ParseObject> myMessages;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String fileType = myMessages.get(position).getString(
            ParseConstants.KEY_FILETYPE);
    ParseFile file = myMessages.get(position).getParseFile(
            ParseConstants.KEY_FILE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getUrl());
    if (fileType.equals(R.string.filetype_image)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewImageActivity.class);
        i.setData(uri);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setData(uri);
        i.setType("video/*");
        startActivity(i);

    }
    List<String> count = myMessages.get(position).getList(
            ParseConstants.KEY_RECEPIENTSIDS);
    if (count.size() == 1) {
        myMessages.get(position).deleteInBackground();
    } else {
        myMessages.get(position).getList(ParseConstants.KEY_RECEPIENTSIDS)
                .remove(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        myMessages.get(position).saveInBackground();

    }

}

private boolean isNetworkAvailableAndConnected() {

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null && info.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isNetworkAvailableAndConnected()) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                ParseConstants.KEY_MESSAGES);
        query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECEPIENTSIDS, ParseUser
                .getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // found messages successfully
                    myMessages = messages;
                    String[] usernames = new String[myMessages.size()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                        usernames[i] = messages.get(i).getString(
                                ParseConstants.KEY_SENDERNAME);

                    }
                    if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
                        MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(
                                getListView().getContext(), myMessages);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        // refill
                        ((MessageAdapter) getListView().getAdapter())
                                .refill(myMessages);

                    }

                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getListView().getContext());
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.messages_loading_failed);
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }

            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}
The logcat is

```
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:386)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at android.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:280)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at com.example.friendsapp.InboxFragment$1.done(InboxFragment.java:116)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at com.parse.Parse$4$1.run(Parse.java:792)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-08 00:06:22.444: E/AndroidRuntime(26541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Is there a way to accomplish the work done by the findInBackgound fulfilled without causing the crash. Or is the crash due to any other logical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are selecting the device from the DDMS window and that you have All Messages selected or a derivative of what you want shown in the Saved Filters segment.  Don't type anything in the search field above either if you don't want things filtered out.  Unplug and replug the device tends to work as well to fix things on occassion.

If this is the first time, then you need to allow communication with your device by turning on USB Debugging within the settings.  This is done by first turning on Developer Options which you can research.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer from a blog. I need to use

```
if(getActivity() != null )
```

before showing up the dialog. Thanks to all.